# Probability of a particular sequence in Lottery

Tags: probability

A typical draw in Britain's national lottery is something like 5,14,27,36,39,45 such that the sample space is the set of all sequences of six different numbers between 1 and 49. What is the probability of a particular set of numbers appearing?

Comment: Well, there are $\binom {49}6=13,983,816$ ways to choose $6$ distinct numbers out of a possible $49$ so...

Comment: since October 2015, the UK National Lottery has had $59$ rather than $49$ balls

Answer (score 1):

There are 49 choose 6 ways to choose 6 distinct numbers from 49. The probability is therefore:
$$ 1/(49! / 43! 6!)= 1/13,983,816 $$
1 in every 13.9 million people if there are 49 numbers to choose from.
However, I believe that the lottery has been changed to 59 choose 6 so the probability would then become:
$$ 1/(59!/53!6!)= 1/45057474 $$
So now the probability of winning is 1 in 45 million.
In general n choose k is equal to: 
$$ n!/k!(n-k)!$$